# Button redirects doesn't work in Android Studio

Tags: android

When I create this project I give the company domain as `eu.kudan.kudansamples`.
When I run this code, I get an error message `Unfortunatly, ArMcqEvaluator has stopped`

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="kudan.eu.armcqevaluator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:text="Email : "
        android:id="@+id/emailtxt"
        android:layout_x="29dp"
        android:layout_y="78dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:text="Password : "
        android:id="@+id/passwordtxt"
        android:layout_x="29dp"
        android:layout_y="114dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_x="105dp"
        android:layout_y="60dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_x="105dp"
        android:layout_y="93dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_x="180dp"
        android:layout_y="156dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Resistor"
        android:id="@+id/registor"
        android:layout_x="82dp"
        android:layout_y="156dp"
        android:onClick="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description" />


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package kudan.eu.armcqevaluator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import eu.kudan.kudan.ARAPIKey;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

    Button login,registor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ARAPIKey key = ARAPIKey.getInstance();
        key.setAPIKey("GAWAE-FBVCC-XA8ST-GQVZV-93PQB-X7SBD-P6V4W-6RS9C-CQRLH-78YEU-385XP-T6MCG-2CNWB-YK8SR-8UUQ");

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        registor = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registor);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registration.class));
    }

}
```

**regigtration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email :"
        android:id="@+id/emaillbl"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="35dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name :"
        android:id="@+id/namelbl"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="70dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="55dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Institute :"
        android:id="@+id/institutelbl"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="105dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/institute"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="91dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Position :"
        android:id="@+id/positionlbl"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="150dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="127dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password :"
        android:id="@+id/passwordlbl"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="186dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="163dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Conform password :"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_x="39dp"
        android:layout_y="224dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/conformpassword"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="196dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_x="130dp"
        android:layout_y="253dp" />


</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**Registration.java**

```
package kudan.eu.armcqevaluator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the full error log

Comment: Check your ManiActivity class. I could find an import like import eu.kudan.kudan.ARAPIKey; which should be the error.

Comment: onClick is supposed to reference a method, not a resource. The method needs to exist in your class, must be public, and needs to have a View passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call override methods from XML onClick. Implement a public method and do your functionality on that method.

on XML file:

```
android:onClick="RedirectRegisterMethod"/>
```

on java file:

```
public void RedirectRegisterMethod(View v) {
// do your functionality here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add onClickListener method to your button.

```
registor.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then only the onclickListener will work for that button.

Also check for activity entry in manifest file for registration activity.